# Exotic matter out of a "squeezed" vacuum?

Tags: general-relativity, warp-drives, nasa, exotic-matter

In the light of the current warp field experiments by NASA I found this paper:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5682

Could this actually lead to the creation of exotic matter or at least strengthen the case that a warp drive, or a least a warp field is possible to create?

Comment: What warp field experiments?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g.,  http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.5682

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed generate energy densities lower than that of the vacuum using squeezed vacuum, or more generally [squeezed coherent states](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.3003). Those states have been experimentally produced, and are commonly used for high precision interferometry due to their low uncertainty in one variable.

The problem of squeezed states is that while they can have negative energy densities, on average (over a period of time), their energy will still be positive (or 0, in the case of the renormalized squeezed vacuum). This is known as the quantum inequalities, which states that, in some cases, you have the following condition on energy :

\begin{equation}
\int dt \langle T_{\mu\nu} X^\mu X^\nu \rangle_\omega g(t) \geq f(t)
\end{equation}

Basically that the average energy over a function of time will be superior to some value. While interesting, it is doubtful that they would be that useful for any spacetime shenanigans such as warp drives.

As for the warp drive itself, do not get too excited either. The details of the warp field experiment are rather vague, no scientific paper on it has been published, and from what I've gathered, it seems mostly to be just about measuring spacetime effects from EM fields, nothing more specific. A task, which, according to [the only paper on the topic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.7772), it probably cannot accomplish.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

In this paper they speak of separating the negative energy density out of a vacuum. This is something we barely understand as it is, and to say that it could lead to anything like a warp-drive is a tremendous leap of faith.